# Why the Horizontal line in text fields are conflicting in Landscape mode in ipad in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, landscape-portrait, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I am using this code in Xcode 9, iOS 11.

```
var boolName: Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    if boolName == true {
        self.designTextField()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if boolName == false {

        self.designTextField()
        boolName = true
    }
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func designTextField() {
    //Set the horizontal line in bottom of text field
    nameLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tfName.bounds.size.height, width: self.tfName.bounds.size.width, height: 1)
    nameLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    tfName.layer.addSublayer(nameLayer)

    //Set the horizontal line in bottom of text field
    phoneLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tfPhone.bounds.size.height, width: self.tfPhone.bounds.size.width, height: 1)
    phoneLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    tfPhone.layer.addSublayer(phoneLayer)

    //Set the horizontal line in bottom of text field
    emailLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tfEmail.bounds.size.height, width: self.tfEmail.bounds.size.width, height: 1)
    emailLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    tfEmail.layer.addSublayer(emailLayer)
}
```

When using that code and testing in iPad. And the issue is when i rotate the iPad in Landscape Mode, then the horizontal line of text fields(in bottom) are conflicting.

[image: iPad in Portrait Mode]

[image: iPad in Landscape Mode]

Can somebody plzz help ?

Comment: check its trailing constraints, for iPad landscape size class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case `if boolName == false` stops the redrawing on landscape mode, remove it. And in method designTextField, set the line layers' names, then you are able to get and update them.

```
let kLineName = "nameLine"

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.designTextField()
}

func designTextField()
{
    //Set the horizontal line in bottom of text field
    if let index = tfName.layer.sublayers?.index(where: { (layer) -> Bool in
        return layer.name == kLineName
    }) {
        //Update line's frame if it's existed.
        let nameLayer = tfName.layer.sublayers![index]
        nameLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tfName.bounds.size.height, width: self.tfName.bounds.size.width, height: 1)
    }
    else{
        //Add layer if it's not existed.
        nameLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tfName.bounds.size.height, width: self.tfName.bounds.size.width, height: 1)
        nameLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        nameLayer.name = kLineName
        tfName.layer.addSublayer(nameLayer)
    }

    //Same to the phoneLayer and emailLayer ......

}
```

Comment: but when i tap on that text field then this line background color will remain same (i want to change this blue color)

Comment: You can use same way to get the layer and change the color in UITextFieldDelegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing`.

Comment: but this will not change the color